# Transform rows to multiple rows in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a problem where I need to transform one row to multiple rows. This is based on a different mapping that I have. I have tried to provide an example below.

Suppose I have a parquet file with the below schema

```
ColA, ColB, ColC, Size, User
```

I need to aggregate the above data into multiple rows based on a lookup map. Suppose I have a static map

```
ColA, ColB, Sum(Size)
ColB, ColC, Distinct (User)
ColA, ColC, Sum(Size)
```

This means that one row in the input RDD needs to be transformed to 3 aggregate. I believe RDD is the way to go with FlatMapPair, but I am not sure how to go about this.

I am also OK to concat the columns into one key, something like `ColA_ColB` etc.

For creating multiple aggregates from the same data, I have started with something like this

```
val keyData: PairFunction[Row, String, Long] = new PairFunction[Row, String, Long]() {
    override def call(x: Row) = {
      (x.getString(1),x.getLong(5))
    }
  }

val ip15M = spark.read.parquet("a.parquet").toJavaRDD

val pairs = ip15M.mapToPair(keyData)

java.util.List[(String, Long)] = [(ios,22), (ios,23), (ios,10), (ios,37), (ios,26), (web,52), (web,1)]
```

I believe I need to do flatmaptopair instead of mapToPair. On similar lines, I tried

```
  val FlatMapData: PairFlatMapFunction[Row, String, Long] = new PairFlatMapFunction[Row, String, Long]() {
    override def call(x: Row) = {
      (x.getString(1),x.getLong(5))
    }
  }
```

but it is giving Error

```
Expression of type (String, Long) doesn't conform to expected type util.Iterator[(String, Long)]
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if I need to add any more details.

Answer (score 0):

the outcome should only have 3 columns? I mean col1, col2, col3 (the agg outcome).
The second aggregate is a distinct count of users? (I assume yes).

If so you can basically create 3 data frames and then union them.
Something in the way of:

val df1 = spark.sql("select colA as col1, colB as col2 ,sum(Size) as colAgg group by colA,colB")

val df2 = spark.sql("select colB as col1, colC as col2 ,Distinct(User) as colAgg group by colB,colC")

val df3 = spark.sql("select colA as col1, colC as col2 ,sum(Size) as colAgg group by colA,colC")

df1.union(df2).union(df3)

Comment: I do not want to do multiple union, since in prod, I would have ~200 aggregates. If I use dataframe, maybe I should be able to some flatmap, but I am not sure how